# Implement typedef in Java

Tags: java

I have a type Time32 that is used in generics as `Work<Time32>` so i made a class Time32. 
I also have  to implement

```
typedef UInt(5) Time32
```

Here UInt means the unsigned int. Java doesn't have unsigned int, so i made my own class.

```
public class UInt 
{
    private final int size;
    public UInt(int x)
    {
       this.size=x;
    }

    public int getSize() 
    {
        return size;
    }
}
```

But i don't understand how i can implement the typedef in java. Please help. Thanks.

I need to keep the UInt class as i have some other variables that will use the Uint like `UInt(20) Load` or `UInt(10) Force`

Comment: can someone please tell how i can achieve the desired i.e. time32 as generic and typedef

Comment: @user Can you please tell us, what this `(5)` should do? That syntax is invalid in any language I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there are no typdefs in Java you cannot use them. The best approximation might be this:

```
public class Time32 extends UInt {
    public Time32(){
        super(5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't. :(  I am working a library which will allow you do do it in Java, but early days yet. ;)

I just use `int` and make sure I know its unsigned and use workarounds, or I use `long` instead and only worry about it when it matters.

Comment: Did you mean "sure I know it's signed" Peter?

Comment: I mean you can use `int` as any 32-bit value, signed or unsigned. Java only supports signed directly, but you can use workarounds to treat it as unsigned.

Comment: Ouch. I'm not sure I'd recommend that.  We used to do such things in C every day but doing it in Java seems to be rarely necessary.

Comment: Agreed, usually it is unneeded as you can use `long`.  If you **really** do need an "unsigned" int, you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no typedefs (or aliases for that matter) in java.
You can either use directly *primitive types* or *wrap* your type inside another one.

```
public class Time32 {
   private final UInt value;
   public Time32(...) {
     value = ...;
     if (value.getSize() != 5) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException()
     }
   }
   public UInt toUInt() {
     return value;
   }
}
```