# Something like "typedef" for Java's EnumSet

Tags: java, enums

I'm using `EnumSet<Foo>` in multiple places.  I'd like to create a `EnumSetFoo` class so I could do `EnumSetFoo xyz = EnumSet.of(Foo.BAR)`, but subclassing `EnumSet` doesn't seem to be the way to go.  Is there a way of achieving this effect in Java?

Comment: Another - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327281/implement-typedef-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have typedefs, but `EnumSet.of()` returns a typed [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html), and you shouldn't need anything more.

You don't *need* to cast it to anything to use what's returned:

```
 EnumSst<Foo> e = EnumSet.of(Foo.BAR);
```

If you really want to use your own class, provide an appropriate constructor and pass the above to it or pass instances of the enum in to a typed varargs constructor:

```
public class EnumSetFoo extends EnumSet<Foo> {
    public EnumSetFoo(Foo... foos) {
        addAll(Arrays.asList(foos));
    }
}
```

or whatever.